# Discard all previous versions (set revision number to 1) in svn

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've set-up a server for version control using [subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/), [tortoise-svn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) and [apache](http://httpd.apache.org/) on a windows machine. I made a lot of structural changes, renamed files and directories, re-ordered and re-grouped various different modules of the code, etc.

All that changes got reflected and recorded in the svn. Now I've finalized the structure and now other people will start using it, so, I want to set the version number to 1 across the repository, i.e., set the revision number to 1 of all the files, discarding all previous changes.

Is there a way to do this? I couldn't find anything, or wasn't able to phrase my search properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new repo; check this out to your disk and export the old repo in the checked out dir; add the new files and commit it to the new repo.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `{CURRENT_VERSION_NUMBER}` with the current version number:

```
svnadmin dump /path/to/current/repo -r{CURRENT_VERSION_NUMBER} > svn.dump
svnadmin create /path/to/new/repo
svnadmin load /path/to/new/repo < svn.dump
```

[Source](http://robmayhew.com/delete-parts-of-subversion-history/)